# Word numbered list display wrong numbers

Tags: microsoft-word, list

I have a numbered list in Word that have headings as 1,2,3,4, and sub-headings as 1.1,1.2,2.1,2.2, etc. So, something like this

1. Heading 1

   1.1. Sub-heading 1.1

   1.2. Sub-heading 1.2
2. Heading 2

   2.1. Sub-heading 2.1

   2.2. Sub-heading 2.2

All the heading/sub-headings in section 1 are OK. However, when I try to cut and paste 1.1 into section 2, it gets numbered as 1.3 instead of 2.1, and I can't find any option to change it to the correct section (2). I can either "Restart at 1" which makes it 1.1, or "Continue numbering, which makes it 1.3.

There's also a "Set Numbering Value", but that only lets me manually change the minor value and not the major value, i.e. I can change it to 1.100, but I can't change it to 2.1.

How do I make the sub-headings the correct number?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in Word-2010. When I cut and paste 1.1 or drag and drop it with Make copy (Ctrl pressed) I obtain the result with proper numbering. Add detailed step-by-step order of reproducing your problem.

Comment: Just to clarity ... are you using Heading Styles or is this a Body Text style of multi-level list?